# Laravel Authority - how to call Authority::can() as another user?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using the **[Authority](https://github.com/machuga/authority-l4)** package for access control in my Laravel application (which I'm upgrading from Laravel 3 to Laravel 4). For unit testing of the access rules, I need to be able to call **Authority::can()** as another user.

In [Laravel 3 Authority](https://github.com/Vespakoen/authority-laravel), I used the **as_user()** method:

```
Authority::as_user($user);
$this->assertTrue(Authority::cannot('read', 'Notifications')); //true

Authority::as_user($superuser);
$this->assertTrue(Authority::can('read', 'Notifications')); //true
```

In [Laravel 4 Authority](https://github.com/machuga/authority-l4), some of the syntax/APIs have changed and **as_user()** no longer exists. I've tried two alternatives but I'm not getting expected results.

**Attempt 1 (use Auth::login() to switch user):**

```
Auth::login($user);
$this->assertTrue(Authority::cannot('read', 'Notifications')); //true
Auth::logout();

Auth::login($superuser);
$this->assertTrue(Authority::can('read', 'Notifications')); //false (wrong!)
Auth::logout();
```

Printing *Auth::user()->name* in the test shows the user has been switched. But printing *$this->getCurrentUser()->name* as a hack inside the *Authority::can()* function shows the user is not being switched within this scope (hence the wrong result).

**Attempt 2: (use Authority::setCurrentUser() to switch user)**

```
Authority::setCurrentUser($user);
$this->assertTrue(Authority::cannot('read', 'Notifications')); 

Authority::setCurrentUser($superuser);
$this->assertTrue(Authority::can('read', 'Notifications')); 

//exception!
```

But in this case I get an exception:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
/var/www/project/app/config/packages/machuga/authority-l4/config.php:9
```

Line 9 in the Authority config file where the exception happens suggests the current user is not being set as expected:

```
8: $user = $authority->getCurrentUser();
9: if(count($user->roles) === 0) return false;
```

For normal application usage (i.e. not switching users within unit tests) Authority appears to be behaving as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of the Laravel 4 Authority module (Matthew Machuga) recommended testing against a new instance of Authority (NB: not the façade). This also requires reloading the ruleset:

```
$rules = Config::get('authority-l4::initialize', null);

$authority = new Authority\Authority($user);
$rules($authority);
$this->assertTrue(Authority::cannot('read', 'Notifications')); //true

$authority = new Authority\Authority($superuser);
$rules($authority);
$this->assertTrue(Authority::can('read', 'Notifications')); //true
```

The full discussion can be seen on the [Laravel forum](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=14531).